# Consulta SQL a varias tablas obtengo datos duplicados

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos de una guardería. Un alumno puede desayunar, almorzar, merender, etc... Quiero obtener los datos de todos los alumnos y que muestren en el día de hoy lo que han hecho. Pero al realizar la consulta, si un alumno a desayunado y también a almorzado aparece dos veces, cuando debe de aparecer solo una vez. De igual forma, quiero obtener SOLO los datos de hoy. También me muestra al alumno duplicado si le añado el desayuno hoy y también lo tenía ayer.

```
$hoy = date("j, n, Y"); 

"select * FROM laguarde1 l 
LEFT join caca c on l.ref=c.ref_caca 
LEFT JOIN siesta s on  l.ref=s.ref_siesta
LEFT JOIN desayuno d on l.ref=d.ref_desayuno
LEFT JOIN almuerzo a on l.ref=a.ref_almuerzo
LEFT JOIN merienda m on l.ref=m.ref_merienda 
AND c.fecha_caca LIKE'%{$hoy}%' 
or s.fecha_siesta LIKE'%{$hoy}%'
or d.fecha_desayuno LIKE'%{$hoy}%'
or a.fecha_almuerzo LIKE'%{$hoy}%'
or m.fecha_merienda LIKE'%{$hoy}%'";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al añadir las fk a la tabla laguarde1 de da el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado con `SELECT DISTINCT ...`?

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar replicar tu entorno y plantear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes mal el modelo de la base de datos.

En las relación 1:N de un modelo relacional, el que hacer la referencia a la forenkey es el que posee la relación N.

En tu caso es la tabla `laguarde`

Cambia esto y lo tendrás solucionado.

Comment: Ok. Lo que me quieres decir es que las claves ref_siesta, ref_desayuno, etc... deben de ir incluidas en la tabla la guarde1?

Comment: si asi es es correcto. Pruebalo y lo comentas.

Comment: Como ha ido, ya lo tienes?

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices. Lo estoy haciendo con el diseñador de phpMyadmin y no sé bien como hacerlo, puedes indicarme algún video donde pueda verlo?

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n

Comment: Al querer añadir la fk a la tabla laguarde1 me devuelve el error #1452. Lo edito arriba.

Comment: Vale, no podía relacionarlos porque la tabla a la que hacía referencia tenía datos. Al eliminar los datos de la tabla ya si me permite la relación. El problema ahora es que al insertar datos en las tablas con fk referenciadas no puedo insertar ya que no existe la fk. Rechazará cualquier operación INSERT o UPDATE que intente crear un valor de clave foránea en una tabla secundaria si no hay un valor de clave candidata coincidente en la tabla primaria.

Comment: Gracias Srsole, en realidad resolviste mi duda. Esta cuestión que planteo, en realidad sería más conveniente plantearla  como nueva. De manera, que la hago nueva.  Gracias por tu ayuda.