# Insertar registro en tabla relacionada

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Al intentar insertar datos en la tabla siesta estando relacionada con la tabla laguarde1 no permite la inserción. Si quito la relación entre ellas, si que permite la inserción en la tabla siesta. Entiendo que es la clave foránea la que me está haciendo alguna restricción. ¿Como debo de realizar el insert en la tabla siesta estando ambas realcionadas?

```
    $referencia_alumno = $_POST['referencia_alumno'];
$nuevo_valor= $_POST['nuevo_valor'];
$hoy = date("j, n, Y"); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO siesta (fecha_siesta, tiempo_siesta, ref_siesta) VALUES ('$hoy','$nuevo_valor','$referencia_alumno')";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da el siguiente error :

INSERT INTO `siesta` (`id_siesta`, `fecha_siesta`, `tiempo_siesta`, `ref_siesta`) VALUES ('0', '20 min', '10, 6, 2020', 'Campanilla 1')
MySQL ha dicho: ￼

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laguarde`.`siesta`, CONSTRAINT `siesta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_siesta`) REFERENCES `laguarde1` (`id_siesta_fk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Pon la query del insert para poder ayudarte

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con la query.

Comment: Me parece que la relación está al revés: un registro de `siesta` debería poder tener muchos registros en `laguarde1` y no al contrario, y creo que está igual en las otras tablas. Así como está nunca te va a dejar insertar un registro en `siesta` sin un key válido en `laguarde1`

Comment: Pués la verdad cambié la relación a partir de está otra cuestión: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363406/consulta-sql-a-varias-tablas-obtengo-datos-duplicados/363411#363411 que duplicaba la visión de los alumnos y no sé bien como hacerlo.

Comment: Muestra tambien el error para poder darte una solucion, recuerda que la relacion siempre hay una tabla depediente y una independiente cuando uno a varios

Comment: He añadido el error que da.